# replacing the value of a variable in url

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

So I have a URL which is mentioned in the following example; I want to change the value of pageToken to "baz"; but my following attempt is replacing pageToken as well; what is the right way to just change the value of pageToken?

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?&pageToken=CDIQAQ&foo=bar"
var res = url.replace(/pageToken=\w*/g, "baz");
console.log(res);
//res is now: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?&baz&foo=bar, but my desired output is https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?&pageToken=baz&foo=bar
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just replace it with "pageToken=baz" ?  The expression is matching, so the replacement is legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work also:

```
var res = url.replace(/(pageToken=)\w*/g, "$1baz");
```

Comment: Nice, I was trying to remember the syntax. You beat me by a second before I was going to update to include this.

Comment: I knew if I waited long enough someone would anyway. 8)

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to include "pageToken=" in the new text:

```
var res = url.replace(/pageToken=\w*/g, "pageToken=baz");
```